# SSRS reports not loading with https

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2019

We are currently trying to configure SSRS 2019. We had installed the report server configuarion manager, and followed the steps to do the custom form authentication.
Now, the reports are loading internally in the report server configuration manager for http. But when we try to access that with https it is not loading up.
Link referenced for the custom form authentication:
https://github.com/microsoft/Reporting-Services/tree/master/CustomSecuritySample2016
Error: 500 internal server error while accessing the https://domain:443/reports link
http://domain:80/reports link works
Can someone please let me know what I am missing here?
[Webportal url configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwpnN.png)
[Internal server error for https](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAclR.png)

Answer (score 0):

Done the following

1. folder permission
2. machine key reverified
3. Checked the reserved URL(There wasn't added in the url. So added)
   Note :- https url added through config file. by stopping report server